# Regex в условиях MySQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql

В PHP использую :

```
$title= preg_replace('/(\w+)/', "$1", $my_title);
```

Если ввожу `My title, is $ & cool`, то получу : `My title is cool`

Теперь в mysql есть `My title, is $ & cool`. Если сравню его с `My title is cool` он должен вернут `true`. Что то типа :

```
where Regex(title,"(\w+)")=`My title is cool`  как это сделать в `mysql`?
```

Comment: Давайте я как доктор хаус пациентам на слово верить не буду.  - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f76ca8988d8788336fa9c4db686a87b9a08ecf60

Comment: *как это сделать в `mysql`* Что - ЭТО? Формулируйте задачу, а не свои (как показывает тест предыдущего оратора - кривые) попытки её решить...